# l2tp/ipsec unable to connect on linux

Tags: linux-networking, ipsec, strongswan, l2tp, xl2tpd

I'm trying to connect to cisco l2tp/ipsec vpn with PSK and IKEv1 username/password.

According to [this article](https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp/wiki/Known-Issues#querying-vpn-server-for-its-ikev1-algorithm-proposals), I've found that server supports following authentification methods:

```
SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=MD5 Group=2:modp1024 Auth=PSK LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration=28800)
SA=(Enc=3DES Hash=SHA1 Group=2:modp1024 Auth=PSK LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration=28800)
SA=(Enc=AES KeyLength=128 Hash=SHA1 Group=2:modp1024 Auth=PSK LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration=28800)
SA=(Enc=AES KeyLength=256 Hash=SHA1 Group=2:modp1024 Auth=PSK LifeType=Seconds LifeDuration=28800)
```

I'm using `networkmanager-l2tp` package. Tried both `openswan` and `libreswan` (manually built with `USE_DH2=true` as described in [this patchnote](https://lists.libreswan.org/pipermail/swan/2020/003438.html)).

My `.nmconnection` file looks like this:

```
[connection]
id=etis
uuid=70147d0a-5d7f-467a-80ee-9048601960e1
type=vpn
permissions=user:***:;

[vpn]
gateway=vpn.psu.ru
ipsec-enabled=yes
ipsec-esp=aes128-sha1,3des-md5
ipsec-ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024
ipsec-psk=***
password-flags=1
user=***
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp
```

When I'm trying to connect I'm getting the following log:

[log using strongswan](https://gist.github.com/lesf0/f99d1e260c363d8ad8ac516a6a13a5dd)

[log using libreswan with USE_DH2=true](https://gist.github.com/lesf0/a9b06b9b722dcc0659cad9b08ac18537)

From what I see, it seems like both ways `ipsec` connection is being established successfully, but then this happens:

```
xl2tpd[106869]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701
xl2tpd[106869]: Connecting to host 212.192.80.206, port 1701
xl2tpd[106869]: death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received
```

Strongswan log also has this suspicious message in between of the above:

```
charon[78694]: 01[NET] received packet: from 212.192.80.206[4500] to 192.168.5.28[4500] (164 bytes)
charon[78694]: 01[IKE] received retransmit of response with ID 1610789051, but next request already sent
```

At this point I've depleted my google skills. If anybody could tell me where to go next or at least tell me if this problem is connected with `ipsec` or `l2tp` part of the equation, I would greately appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

The `no acceptable traffic selectors found` error in the logs is described on the following page which also has a workaround :

- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp/wiki/Known-Issues#strongswan-no-acceptable-traffic-selectors-found

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/500780)